# wp_set_object_terms not updating database without a die()

Tags: plugin-development, actions, attachments

I have added custom taxonomy to media attachments. From the individual post page these are updating correctly, with some tweaks to get the column count updating correctly - and I can see these changes in the admin/database without a problem.

In the media popup, I can change the taxonomy and using the `edit_attachment` action I can see `wp_set_object terms` is firing, I can also see that it returns an array with the correct IDs in for the updated term:

```
wp_set_object_terms($id, $cat_ids, 'attachment_category', false);
//returns
array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "3"
}
```

3 being the correct ID for the term in question, however I cannot see an update in the database and when I refresh the page or close/reopen the popup the change is reverted.

Why is `wp_set_object_terms` in this case not updating the database but thinking it is successful? `edit_attachment` is the only action which correctly fired for me when the `save-attachment-compat` action is triggered on the form. If I add a `die();` at the end of my function, and stop any further changes, it updates the database, is this the correct behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Before using `$cat_ids` in the `wp_set_object_terms()` function, cast all values from the string to a number.

Note from the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms):

> Integers are interpreted as tag IDs. **Warning**: some functions may return `term_ids` as strings which will be interpreted as slugs consisting of numeric characters!

Comment: Yes that's already done, cat_ids values are IDs, explicitly set with (int)$value, and the `wp_set_object_terms` fires correctly, but gets overwritten without a `die()` - which is the question, why does it need the `die()` ?